# Use two different AWS resources hosted in two different regions in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I want to use my "Dynamodb DocumentClient" which is hosted in 'us-west-2' region and SES which is hosted in 'us-west-1' region, in one lambda function. How can I do it?

Answer (score 7):

When you initialize an AWS SDK client you can specify the region for the client to use, like this:

```
var ses = new AWS.SES({region: 'us-west-1'});
var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-west-2'})
```

Comment: I have been using this setup for a while now,cI am facing Networking errors. Does such setup invite any Networking errors specially write EPROTO errors?

Comment: @hrushilok this would be unrelated to your network errors.